# Bootstrap time is disappear after appear

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My CSS is like below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My JavaScript code is like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.datewithtime').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
            showTodayButton: true,
            showClear: true,
            toolbarPlacement: 'bottom'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am getting output like below.

[image]

Comment: then, what is your question ?

Comment: Thanks @trysetyoutomo. How can I display Time here ?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo. All code should be included in the question instead of through an outside source.

Comment: can you click the calendar icon ? it should be change the UI to time display @abuabu

Comment: Thanks @trysetyoutomo. I clicked on Calendar icon. Nothing is happen.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check the following snippet here, it will show date + time

```js
 $(function () {
             $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
         });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
               <input type='text' class="form-control datewithtime" />
               <span class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
               </span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```